# SendMessage to execute button and wait until it's finished

Tags: delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I am using application A to control application B. I used **SendMessage** to execute a button in application B. After button in application B is executed, application A do another task without waiting application B finish its task. How can I wait a process of click button in application B finished before starting another task of application A?

```
begin
  ParentWindow := FindWindow('TfrmMain', nil);
  if (ParentWindow = 0) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('App cannot be found!!');
    Exit;
  end;

  // Get handle of Combobox
  Memo_temP.Clear;
  EnumChildWindows(ParentWindow, @EnumChildrenTComboBox, UINT_PTR(Memo_temP.Lines));
  temStr := Memo_temP.Lines.Strings[0];
  ComboboxHWND := StrToInt64('$' + temStr);

  // Get handle of output vaule
  Memo_temP.Clear;
  EnumChildWindows(ParentWindow, @EnumChildrenTMemo, UINT_PTR(Memo_temP.Lines));
  temStr := Memo_temP.Lines.Strings[0];
  MemoTxt2HWND := StrToInt64('$' + temStr);

  // Get handle of btn
  Memo_temP.Clear;
  EnumChildWindows(ParentWindow, @EnumChildrenTButton, UINT_PTR(Memo_temP.Lines));
  temStr := Memo_temP.Lines.Strings[1];
  if (temStr = '') then begin ShowMessage('Error4'); Exit; end;
  AsyncRunTestHWND := StrToInt64('$' + temStr);

  i := -1;
  while True do
  begin
    Inc(i);

    // Select each item in ComboBox
    SendMessage(ComboboxHWND, CB_SETCURSEL, i, 0);
    SendMessage(ComboboxHWND, WM_COMMAND, MakeWParam(0, CBN_SELCHANGE), ComboboxHWND);

    // Click btn
    SendMessage(AsyncRunTestHWND, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MakeLParam(5, 5));
    SendMessage(AsyncRunTestHWND, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MakeLParam(5, 5));

    // get result text from memo
    BufLen := SendMessage(MemoTxt2HWND, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    SetLength(Buffer, BufLen + 1);
    SendMessage(MemoTxt2HWND, WM_GETTEXT, BufLen, LParam(PChar(Buffer)));

    if (PosEx('Error', Buffer) > 0) then
      Memo_Error.Lines.Add(Buffer)
    else
      Memo_Succeed.Lines.Add(Buffer);

    if SendMessage(ComboboxHWND, CB_SETCURSEL, i, 0) < 0 then Break;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: `SendMessage()` waits only until the sent message is replied to. That doesn't mean the app being clicked on can't start tasks asynchronously when its button is clicked. Without knowing exactly what tasks you are interested in, there is very likely little to no way to determine when those tasks are actually finished, unless maybe there is a UI update you can look for remotely.

Comment: Let's me explain more about my purpose. When I click button in application B, I will get result as text in memo of application B. Then I have to copy text in memo of application B to show in memo of application A. The problem is that when application B running its task (memo of application B is empty), application A didn't wait. Application A start to copy empty text from memo of application B. So memo of application A always show result empty.

Comment: I edited my question to add my code. You can check it above.

Comment: so what's stopping you from simply reading the memo's text in a loop or timer until it changes? Or even hooking the memo to be notified when it changes? On a side note, when clicking the button, you can send a single [`BM_CLICK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-click) message instead of sending `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` manually

Comment: You are right. When memo's text is changed, It mean that process of button click is done. So I can get result and continue my loop to other item. But how can i notify that memo's text is changed? In addition, thank you for a tip of **BM_CLICK**. I will check it and change my code.

Comment: Isn't UIAutomation what you actually need?

Comment: @PinkPanther look at `SetWindowsHookEx()` and `SetWinEventHook()` for hooking events, like window messages and text changes. You can get the memo's thread ID using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Honestly, I am not good at Delphi programming. I spend almost 10 days to search write code above. Right now I don't know what you want me to do. But I will take your keyword to search. I am appreciate if there are any easies example code of `SetWindowsHookEx()`, `SetWinEventHook()`, and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`. However, thank you for your suggestion. It help me a lot in searching.